# Accessing gridview from infile javascript aspx.net, paging issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

so here's the situation:

I've got this grid:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="productGrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="PageIndexChanged" PagerSettings-Visible="false"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="Sort">
```

and I'm accessing it like this:

```
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%= productGrid.ClientID %>");
```

Which works, that's fine, but the problem is, when I go `grid.row.length`, I get 21, however the grid is bound to several hundred elements, so the problem is it's only looking at the first page, how do I get it to look at the rest of the data?

I want to iterate through the whole table. Yes I'm sure that the table has been loaded with values before this javascript is executed, the values are on page load and the script is on button click.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your page size is 20 so only 20 rows will be rendered on page.

Comment: So I presume you asked for a paging for your gridview ? Then on client side, only data from current page is available...

Comment: @vijay yeah my point was I wanted all of them. Bartdude that makes more sense, thanks, I guess I have to find a way for it to not be on client side.

Comment: is there not a hidden attribute `data` to the grid?